# open and modify a value from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub abrirotroworkbook()

    Dim y As Workbook ' a donde se va a pegar
    Dim vals As Variant

    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:Path\filename.xlsm")

    'Now, copy what you want from x:

    vals = Sheet12.Range("A3:B3").Value


    'Now, paste to y worksheet:

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A5).Value = vals


End Sub
```

When I run this code it saves the information of the book I have opened in the variable `vals`, then it opens the other workbook, but when it tries to paste in it, the following error appears:

> run time error '9'  subscript out of range

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I assume you forgot to add quotes here `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A5).Value = vals`. It should be `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = vals`, right? And does `Sheet1`exist in your workbook y you openend. That is usually the cause for [runtime error 9](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range) in such a case. Are you also aware that you create an array with `vals = Sheet12.Range("A3:B3").Value` and you only copy the first value of it with `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A5).Value = vals`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was like you said that Sheet1 didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As @Storax said, your variable `vals` is not opening a workbook but creating an array.
You don't need an array for just copying two cells. You would have to loop through the array. The code below is basic. If you are copying from `ThisWorkbook`(the workbook your code is in) it will work. If it is another workbook then you can create another variable to open it, and use the variable instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook 'the source workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:Path\sourcefilename.xlsm") 'change name and path as required

Dim wb2 As Workbook 'the destination workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:Path\destinationfilename.xlsm") 'change name and path as required

wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:B5").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet12").Range("A3:B3").Value  'replace ThisWorkbook with `wb1`
```